# Migrating Custom Push Row to Eureka 4.1

Tags: eureka-forms

I'm having quite a hard time migrating a custom row from a previous version of Eureka (around 3.0) to Eureka 4.1. The custom row is a custom push row so the label can have multiple lines and so the view controller that is pushed can have a custom section header. There may be a better way to accomplish that than having a custom row, so that is one possible solution, but I'm not sure if that's a possibility.

So there are 2 problems: The custom row and the the custom selector view controller. Here's the custom row:

```
open class _StackedPushRow: SelectorRow<StackedPushCell, CustomSelectorViewController<String>> {

    public typealias StackedRow = PushRow<String>

    var dontClearWhenDisabled: Bool = false

    required public init(tag: String?) {
        super.init(tag: tag)
        cellProvider = CellProvider(nibName: "StackedPushCell")

        presentationMode = .show(controllerProvider: ControllerProvider.callback {
            return CustomSelectorViewController<Cell.Value> { _ in } },
         onDismiss: { vc in
            self.cell.update()
            _ = vc.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        })
    }
}

/// A generic inline row where the user can pick an option from a presented view controller
public final class StackedPushRow: _StackedPushRow, RowType {

    required public init(tag: String?) {
        super.init(tag: tag)
    }

}
```

and here's the custom selector view controller:

```
public final class CustomSelectorViewController<T: Equatable>: SelectorViewController<T> {

    open override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        form.first?.header = HeaderFooterView.caliberStyleSectionHeader(title: row.title ?? "")
    }

    static func presentationMode<T: Equatable>() -> PresentationMode<SelectorViewController<T>> {
        return .show(controllerProvider: ControllerProvider.callback {
            return CustomSelectorViewController<T> { _ in }
        }, onDismiss: { vc in
            _ = vc.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        })
    }
}
```

Here are the errors for the custom row:

> /Users/rod/Documents/Development/Caliber/CaliberiOS/H2O/_iOS/H2O/UI/Common/CustomRows/StackedPushRow.swift:78:29:
>   Generic type 'SelectorRow' specialized with too many type parameters
>   (got 2, but expected 1)
>
> /Users/rod/Documents/Development/Caliber/CaliberiOS/H2O/_iOS/H2O/UI/Common/CustomRows/StackedPushRow.swift:85:9:
>   'super' members cannot be referenced in a root class
>   /Users/rod/Documents/Development/Caliber/CaliberiOS/H2O/_iOS/H2O/UI/Common/CustomRows/StackedPushRow.swift:86:9:
>   Use of unresolved identifier 'cellProvider'
>   /Users/rod/Documents/Development/Caliber/CaliberiOS/H2O/_iOS/H2O/UI/Common/CustomRows/StackedPushRow.swift:88:9:
>   Use of unresolved identifier 'presentationMode'
>   /Users/rod/Documents/Development/Caliber/CaliberiOS/H2O/_iOS/H2O/UI/Common/CustomRows/StackedPushRow.swift:98:20:
>   Type 'StackedPushRow' does not conform to protocol 'BaseRowType'
>   /Users/rod/Documents/Development/Caliber/CaliberiOS/H2O/_iOS/H2O/UI/Common/CustomRows/StackedPushRow.swift:98:20:
>   Type 'StackedPushRow' does not conform to protocol 'RowType'
>   /Users/rod/Documents/Development/Caliber/CaliberiOS/H2O/_iOS/H2O/UI/Common/CustomRows/StackedPushRow.swift:98:20:
>   Candidate has non-matching type '(String?, (Self) -> Void)'
>   (Eureka.RowType)
>   /Users/rod/Documents/Development/Caliber/CaliberiOS/H2O/_iOS/H2O/UI/Common/CustomRows/StackedPushRow.swift:98:20:
>   Type 'StackedPushRow' does not conform to protocol 'Taggable'
>   /Users/rod/Documents/Development/Caliber/CaliberiOS/H2O/_iOS/H2O/UI/Common/CustomRows/StackedPushRow.swift:98:20:
>   Type 'StackedPushRow' does not conform to protocol 'TypedRowType'
>   /Users/rod/Documents/Development/Caliber/CaliberiOS/H2O/_iOS/H2O/UI/Common/CustomRows/StackedPushRow.swift:111:9:
>   Use of unresolved identifier 'validationOptions'
>   /Users/rod/Documents/Development/Caliber/CaliberiOS/H2O/_iOS/H2O/UI/Common/CustomRows/StackedPushRow.swift:141:9:
>   'StackedPushRow' is not a subtype of 'BaseRow'

Here are the errors for the custom selector view controller:

> /Users/rod/Documents/Development/Caliber/CaliberiOS/H2O/_iOS/H2O/UI/Common/CustomSelectorViewController.swift:12:64:
>   Type 'T' does not conform to protocol 'OptionsProviderRow'
>   /Users/rod/Documents/Development/Caliber/CaliberiOS/H2O/_iOS/H2O/UI/Common/CustomSelectorViewController.swift:14:24:
>   Method does not override any method from its superclass
>   /Users/rod/Documents/Development/Caliber/CaliberiOS/H2O/_iOS/H2O/UI/Common/CustomSelectorViewController.swift:15:9:
>   'super' members cannot be referenced in a root class
>   /Users/rod/Documents/Development/Caliber/CaliberiOS/H2O/_iOS/H2O/UI/Common/CustomSelectorViewController.swift:17:9:
>   Use of unresolved identifier 'form'
>   /Users/rod/Documents/Development/Caliber/CaliberiOS/H2O/_iOS/H2O/UI/Common/CustomSelectorViewController.swift:17:80:
>   Use of unresolved identifier 'row'
>   /Users/rod/Documents/Development/Caliber/CaliberiOS/H2O/_iOS/H2O/UI/Common/CustomSelectorViewController.swift:22:52:
>   Argument passed to call that takes no arguments

I've read the issues section on Github and seen examples of others running into this, but every time I try to put the examples in to practice, I run into other problems and I just keep running in circles. I could really use some help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`SelectorRow` now only takes a generic Cell type but no view controller. The SelectorViewController is defined by the `presentationMode`. You should declare your row like:
`open class _StackedPushRow: SelectorRow<StackedPushCell>`

For your `CustomSelectorViewController` you need to pass the rowType you are going to use as generic type. That row type must conform to `OptionsProviderRow`, like ListCheckRow for example.

Comment: ListCheckRow doesn't conform to OptionsProviderRow. Could you show an example please?

Comment: Did you fixed your problem?